# ggplot line color "black" becomes red

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used the following script to make the graph below

```
hypttauplot <- qplot(fuclin_csf, fitHYPTTAU, data=selTAU, geom=c("smooth"),
                     method="glm", color='black', linetype=BL_HYPT) +
               theme_classic() + xlab("Time (years)") + ylab("Tau (pg/ml)") +
               scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
               ggtitle("A. Hypertension") +
               theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

But now my questions is: why are the lines red instead of black? And how can I change them to black?

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible (incl. some fake data, feel free to use datasets that come shipped with R)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `I()` to set the aesthetics manually in `qplot()`, e.g. `colour=I("black")` (setting vs. mapping of aesthetics).

```
# mapping
qplot(carat, price, data=diamonds, color="black")
# equivalent to ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(carat, price, color="black")) + geom_point()
```

[image: plot1]

```
# setting
qplot(carat, price, data=diamonds, color=I("black"))
# equivalent to ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(carat, price), color="black") + geom_point()
```

[image: plot2]

You can use `scale_colour_manual` to specify an own set of mappings.

Comment: Thank you! That was the comment I needed :)